# jQuery .map() to pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

Is there a way to convert the following jQuery method to pure javascript?

```
var myProps = 
$(".interp").map(function () {
return this.id; 
}).get();
```

I do not know how many objects will be available each time. There may be 3, 15, 20, etc.. objects in the map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pure JavaScript contains a [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method too, it's on `Array` so you'd need to use it on the `NodeList` returned from [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) generically using [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
var myProps =  Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".interp"),function (el) {
    return el.id; 
});
```

Alternatively, you can convert the `NodeList` to an array and use more compact syntax.

```
function query(selector){
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector),0);
}
```

Which would let you do:

```
query(".interp").map(function(el){
    return el.id;
}
```

Comment: if there is no native support then?

Comment: @ArunPJohny If there is no native support you can shim `.map` pretty easily yourself, MDN contains a pretty good one https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map . It's fine to shim methods that already exist in new JS implementations like `.map` `.filter` `.reduce` and so on :)

Comment: I apologize - I'm still a noob. I added two more closing parenthesis "})));" to close the 'var myProps = Array.prototype ......' call but I get an error that that "documentquerySelectorAll is not defined'

Comment: @bagofmilk Yeah, that was my bad :) I typed it in the browser, querySelectorAll is a method of `document`, so it's `document.querySelectorAll` - note `querySelectorAll` requires IE8 and up so if you need to support older browsers you need to select the elements differently or use a selector engine like sizzle. Also, no need to apologize, if my answer has a problem in it I want to know - that's one of the reasons I come to SO - to be peer reviewed, and it is also part of how I learn.

Comment: Ah cool. Now I get 'undefined is not a function' and it points to the var myProps code. I'm using Chrome BTW.

Comment: There are some important differences between them though.  For example: returning null from `jQuery.map` will remove the element from the resulting array while `Array.map` will contain an element with a null value.  Also the range of elements in `Array.map` is set before the first invocation while I believe in jQuery's version, it is not (not sure about that last one though…)

Comment: @dc5 Nice point! The [jQuery implementation](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.map) is pretty simple, it just calls callback through length and if the result is unstrictly equal to null (like null or undefined for example) it does not add it to the resulting array. jQuery's version also works on objects where in pure JS you'd do `Object.keys(obj).map` . The pure JS ones newer and I believe nicer, learning and being influenced from jQuery - but that's just my subjective opinion.